# SQL Server query not finding row in Database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have this row in my SQL Server database :

```
Province    City                                LocationText
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
İstanbul    İstanbul Sabiha Gökçen Havalimanı   Ä°stanbul Sabiha Gökçen Airport
```

And I copy & paste the city name above as a test in the query below:

```
select * 
from Locations 
where City ='İstanbul Sabiha Gökçen Havalimanı'
```

But the query returns `No Result Found`. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it's an `NVARCHAR` column, you might have better luck with the `N` prefix:

```
select * from Locations where City = N'İstanbul Sabiha Gökçen Havalimanı'
```

Here's a [Microsoft support article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/239530/en-us) describing the use of the `N` prefix when dealing with Unicode values.

Answer (score 1):

My best guess is that this is a known bug in MS SQL Server. Take a look at this [link](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CONFKB/Known+Issues+For+SQL+Server):

> Turkish language. If you're using MS SQL Server you can have problems
>   with TURKISH_CI_AS collation because of this SQL Server bug.

(And another [link](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/382858/field-names-becomes-case-sentive-when-we-use-turkish-ci-as))

I suggest changing the City to exclude the special characters (`İ ö ç ı`) and then add them one by one in order to check which one is the problematic one.